Quoting reference
It would be nice to have some quick way to add references to questions/answers. Maybe simple footnotes would suffice for the time being.
The most convenient in the long-term would be to use some external reference library (probably hard to standardise on one though) and expand those links to reference entries on paste.
I use Mendeley (matter of preference), so an example for an article I tried to reference:
Chopra, 1993

Yes, footnotes are good, and I like your example.  I use Mendeley too; great application.

I don't know how difficult it might be to include a "Reference" system within the StackExchange API, but being able to cite papers in an efficient way could be extremely useful in the whole network in my opinion.
Maybe we could use something similar to BiBTex at the end of the posts for example.

What does Mendeley add? Anything that requires full name along with some download to sign up has me hesitating. It looks so far like some combination of Delicious and LinkedIn.

Mendeley adds a lot of collective knowledge about the document. You don't have to download it from Mendeleye. On the link the OP provided, you can click the "Find this paper at" button to download it from various sources on the internet. I use Mendeley to organize all of my research papers and find it to be awesome and it doesn't cost anything.
